# Shaked animation flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I need shaking animation like this [video](https://youtu.be/nLp98WgEjhI?t=430) 
I'm newbie to Flutter. I would appreciate a solution or a link to the tutorial.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think there can be better solution. But this one works fine, maybe it'll help

```
class TestAnimWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TestAnimWidgetState();
}

class _TestAnimWidgetState extends State<TestAnimWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  final TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
  AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Animation<double> offsetAnimation =
    Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 24.0).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.elasticIn)).animate(controller)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller.reverse();
        }
      });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: offsetAnimation,
                builder: (buildContext, child) {
                  if (offsetAnimation.value < 0.0) print('${offsetAnimation.value + 8.0}');
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: offsetAnimation.value + 24.0, right: 24.0 - offsetAnimation.value),
                    child: Center(child: TextField(controller: textController, )),
                  );
                }),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
              if (textController.value.text.isEmpty) controller.forward(from: 0.0);
            },
            child: Text('Enter'),)
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```